# inetelliJ idea - sbt plugin conflicts with Standalone sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-plugin

I want to setup a Spark-Scala-Sbt dev environment on Ubuntu

So i have installed SBT, Scala Seperately before installing IntelliJ.

But after installing intelliJ i have installed the **sbt** plugin for intelliJ as well.

Now how to avoid conflicts between the 2 sbt's which one to use and how to setup properly to avoid conflict.

Also wanted to know HOW .. the installed Scala & SBT is different from the scala & sbt plugin that comes with itelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 0):

The standalone sbt plugin is obsolete with IntelliJ Scala Plugin 2017.1, which includes an [integrated sbt shell](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2017/03/23/scala-plugin-for-intellij-idea-2017-1-cleaner-ui-sbt-shell-repl-worksheet-akka-support-and-more/) and supports building through that shell.

To avoid any conflicts between different instances of sbt shells, it is best to have only one running at a time - either from the terminal or from IDEA. Other than that you don't need any special setup.